Java Spring - Docker no conecta
Necesito ayuda con lo siguiente, hace mas de 1 hora estoy intentando conectar por primera vez mi aplicacion de java con una BDD utilizando Docker.
Estoy siguiendo un tutorial al paso a paso de youtube y apenas implementa esa persona docker el codigo le corre correctamente, en cambio ami me termina dando un error de autenticacion y no entiendo por que.
Soy bastante nuevo en esto pero si no me equivoco no estoy colocando ningun nombre mal por ende no entiendo por que se finaliza la aplicacion.
Para dar contexto me fije en pgAdmin4 y tengo una BDD dentro de postgresSQL16, llamada postgres.
Mi usuario viendo en las propiedades de eso es localhost, y mi contraseña se que esta correcta por que es la que uso cada vez que me conecto manualmente a la base.
En resumen esto es lo que tengo en mi compose.yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres  
      POSTGRES_USER: localhost  
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: MI CONTRASEÑA  
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'

Este es el log que me da la terminal de IntellIJ :
2024-07-15T18:30:43.057-03:00  INFO 4648 --- [  restartedMain] com.isaac.runnerz.RunnerzApplication     : Starting RunnerzApplication using Java 22 with PID 4648 (C:\Users\Isaac\Desktop\Programacion\IntelliJ\YT\CRUD-BDD\runnerz\target\classes started by Isaac in C:\Users\Isaac\Desktop\Programacion\IntelliJ\YT\CRUD-BDD)
2024-07-15T18:30:43.062-03:00  INFO 4648 --- [  restartedMain] com.isaac.runnerz.RunnerzApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-07-15T18:30:43.303-03:00  INFO 4648 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.d.c.l.DockerComposeLifecycleManager : Using Docker Compose file 'C:\Users\Isaac\Desktop\Programacion\IntelliJ\YT\CRUD-BDD\compose.yaml'
2024-07-15T18:30:45.701-03:00  INFO 4648 --- [utReader-stderr] o.s.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCli   : time="2024-07-15T18:30:45-03:00" level=warning msg="C:\\Users\\Isaac\\Desktop\\Programacion\\IntelliJ\\YT\\CRUD-BDD\\compose.yaml: `version` is obsolete"
2024-07-15T18:30:45.734-03:00  INFO 4648 --- [utReader-stderr] o.s.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCli   :  Container crud-bdd-postgres-1  Created
2024-07-15T18:30:45.740-03:00  INFO 4648 --- [utReader-stderr] o.s.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCli   :  Container crud-bdd-postgres-1  Starting
2024-07-15T18:30:46.705-03:00  INFO 4648 --- [utReader-stderr] o.s.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCli   :  Container crud-bdd-postgres-1  Started
2024-07-15T18:30:46.706-03:00  INFO 4648 --- [utReader-stderr] o.s.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCli   :  Container crud-bdd-postgres-1  Waiting
2024-07-15T18:30:47.245-03:00  INFO 4648 --- [utReader-stderr] o.s.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCli   :  Container crud-bdd-postgres-1  Healthy
2024-07-15T18:30:48.450-03:00  INFO 4648 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2024-07-15T18:30:48.450-03:00  INFO 4648 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2024-07-15T18:30:51.629-03:00  INFO 4648 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-07-15T18:30:51.653-03:00  INFO 4648 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-07-15T18:30:51.654-03:00  INFO 4648 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.25]
2024-07-15T18:30:51.765-03:00  INFO 4648 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-07-15T18:30:51.767-03:00  INFO 4648 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3315 ms
2024-07-15T18:30:52.011-03:00  INFO 4648 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-07-15T18:30:54.429-03:00  INFO 4648 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2024-07-15T18:30:54.534-03:00  INFO 4648 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path '/'
2024-07-15T18:30:54.577-03:00  INFO 4648 --- [  restartedMain] com.isaac.runnerz.RunnerzApplication     : Started RunnerzApplication in 12.8 seconds (process running for 13.942)
2024-07-15T18:30:54.616-03:00  INFO 4648 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-07-15T18:30:55.789-03:00  INFO 4648 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-07-15T18:30:55.830-03:00 ERROR 4648 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:84) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:653) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:723) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:754) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:767) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:820) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForList(JdbcTemplate.java:952) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.DefaultJdbcClient$DefaultStatementSpec$IndexedParamResultQuerySpec.listOfRows(DefaultJdbcClient.java:292) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at com.isaac.runnerz.run.RunRepository.count(RunRepository.java:68) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:354) ~[spring-aop-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768) ~[spring-aop-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-tx-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768) ~[spring-aop-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[spring-aop-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at com.isaac.runnerz.run.RunRepository$$SpringCGLIB$$0.count(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.isaac.runnerz.run.RunJsonDataLoader.run(RunJsonDataLoader.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunner$5(SpringApplication.java:790) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.acceptWithException(ThrowingConsumer.java:83) ~[spring-core-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:60) ~[spring-core-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:88) ~[spring-core-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:798) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:789) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunners$3(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:557) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:546) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:265) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:611) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:342) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at com.isaac.runnerz.RunnerzApplication.main(RunnerzApplication.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: autentica��o do tipo senha falhou para o usu�rio "localhost"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:698) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:207) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:262) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:273) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:446) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:298) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar:42.7.3]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:137) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:360) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:202) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:461) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:550) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:98) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:111) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:160) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:118) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    ... 43 common frames omitted

Basicamente un error con JDBC, pero yo creo que el error principal es este :
FATAL: autentica��o do tipo senha falhou para o usu�rio "localhost"

Es decir que me parece que directamente no esta validando lo que le paso, o estoy haciendo algún tipo de conexión mal, cualquier tipo de consejo sobre que probar lo agradeceria, estuve mas de 1 hora leyendo por internet y no logro hacer que ande ni ayudándome con chatgpt

El mensaje de error (en portugués?) parece indicar que la contraseña que has definido para el usuario localhost en tu aplicación spring no es válida. ¿Has repasado cómo configuras la conexión a la base de datos en spring? Aquí puedes encontrar otro tutorial simple donde se detallan todos los pasos para conectar con una bd postgres dockerizada con spring boot. Puedes repasar si tienes todos los elementos necesarios listados ahí en tu proyecto.

Si das con la clave de lo que está pasando, puedes responder tú mismo la pregunta y que sirva para otros en el futuro :-)

La contraseña estaba correctamente colocada, no se por que era algun error con el archivo compose.yaml, lo solucione creando de vuelta el proyecto con maven y ahi corrio todo correctamente. Desconozco por que creandolo manualmente no me lo reconocia pero usando un proyecto desde cero con maven si
